# Read Access Violation in window procedure wrapper

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a windows api wrapper library. but i am encountering problem: A read access violation is throwed whenever i try to use `this` pointer in the "wrapped" window procedure--the one called from the static version. Here is library interface

```
class widget {
protected:
    HWND hwnd;
public: // instinfo is class that represents WNDCLASS structure
    widget(instinfo ii, const WCHAR *text,
        DWORD styles = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        point ul = DEFUL,
        int cx = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int cy = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND parent = NULL,
        HMENU hm = NULL);
};

class olwindow : public widget {
    // static window proc: It registered by WNDCLASS structure
    static LRESULT CALLBACK baseWinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);
    LRESULT CALLBACK winproc(UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);
protected:
    virtual void LButtonDown(int, int) { } // an example event, is override by classes that inherit and wanna customize
public:
    friend class instinfo;

    olwindow(instinfo ii, const WCHAR *cap, point ul = DEFUL, 
        int cx = CW_USEDEFAULT, int cy = CW_USEDEFAULT);
};
```

The relevant functions are `baseWinProc` and `winproc`, which i show below:

```
LRESULT olwindow::baseWinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    olwindow *w;

    if (wm == WM_NCCREATE)
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG) ((CREATESTRUCT *) lp)->lpCreateParams);

    w = (olwindow *) GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);
    if (w)
        w->winproc(wm, wp, lp);
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, wm, wp, lp);
}

LRESULT olwindow::winproc(UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (wm) {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            // on line below is crash
            this->LButtonDown(GET_X_LPARAM(lp), GET_Y_LPARAM(lp));
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
>
> this-> was 0x12A07E0.

what could this mean?

Edit: Here is the constructor of `widget` class, it is called by the constructor of `olwindow`

```
widget::widget(instinfo ii, const WCHAR * text, DWORD styles, point ul, 
         int cx, int cy, HWND parent, HMENU hm)
{
    this->hwnd = CreateWindow(ii.getClassName(), text, styles, 
         ul.x, ul.y, cx, cy, parent, hm, ii.getHinst(), this);
    if (this->hwnd == NULL)
        MessageBox(NULL, getErrMsg(), L"", 0);
    ShowWindow(this->hwnd, SW_SHOW);
}

olwindow::olwindow(instinfo ii, const WCHAR * cap, point ul, int cx, int cy) :
    widget(ii, cap, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, ul, cx, cy)
{ }
```

Comment: Are you compiling for a 64-bit target? Because, if you do, you are truncating your pointers, both by using a `(LONG)` cast, as well as calling `[S|G]etWindowLong` (vs. `[S|G]etWindowLongPtr`).

Comment: @IInspectable yes, my machine is 64 bit windows

Comment: That wasn't the question I was asking. So here it goes again: Are you compiling for a 64-bit target?

Comment: @IInspectable Im targeting x86

Comment: Since you are (supposedly) feeding a `this`-pointer through the call to `CreateWindow[Ex]`, you need to show that code. Ideally a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable edited the question, sorry for not including it from the beginning

Comment: The `this` pointer in your `widget` c'tor (which you are passing to `CreateWindow`) is not of type `olwindow*`. Your cast to `olwindow*` is invalid.

Comment: you need in any case use `SetWindowLongPtr` `GetWindowLongPtr` and `LONG_PTR` for user data

Comment: and why not some debug ? at which point exactly exception ? on which window message ?

Comment: @RbMm: For 32-bit targets there is no requirement to call `[S|G]etWindowLongPtr`. Those APIs are only strictly required, when compiling for 64-bit targets.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you very much, that was the mistake i made, please write as answer and i will accept

Comment: @IInspectable - formally yes, but code become unportable and will be work only for 32 bit system. why not just write correct code, which will be work for both 32/64 ?

Comment: @RbMm: Recommending to use a 64-bit compatible API, and implying that it were required for 32-bit code are not the same thing. The latter is wrong, which I explained in my previous comment.

Comment: @IInspectable - really when not defined (_WIN64) `SetWindowLongPtr` defined as macro `#define SetWindowLongPtrW   SetWindowLongW` - so if use *Ptr* version code will be correct for both 32/64 bit target. if write `SetWindowLongW` direct in code - it can be used only for 32 bit

Comment: @RbMm: I don't disagree with the recommendation to write 64-compatible code. I disagree with the statement, that using the `*Ptr` versions were always required. That's just wrong, and I pointed out as much. It seems you still can't take constructive criticism, without struggling to make the wrong sound right. Can't you just accept that you were wrong, and let it rest?

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, you right here. i was not correct at begin. not clear state that use *Ptr* version not mandatory if restrict self only for 32 bit target. but best way in any case

Comment: @IInspectable i have one more question. in class `olwindow`, i added another virtual function like `LButtonDown`, it is call `duringCreate`. It is called in `case WM_CREATE` in `winproc`. The problem is, it calls the `duringCreate` function that's **in the `olwindow` class** instead of the one in the derived class. Could it be because on `WM_CREATE` the window hasn't been created yet?

Comment: state of window and c++ class inheritance/virtual functions - absolute unrelated things. this can be only if you again some mistake with class pointers, etc.

Comment: @RbMm: They are indeed very much related in this case: The `CreateWindow` call in the base class calls into several message handlers, before it returns. These message handlers assume a fully constructed derived class' instance. Which does not yet exist, because we are still in the base class c'tor.

Comment: @SeanHigh: `WM_CREATE` is indeed sent to the window procedure, before `CreateWindow` returns. I'll write up a complete answer, when time permits.

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, you right - i even not take in account that `CreateWindow` called from constructor.. this is very bad design. in constructor must be only simply initialization and separate method like `Create`. in this case will be no dependence on c++ class hierarchy.

Comment: @IInspectable i actually solved the issue. It was caused by `CreateWindow` call be in constructor of `olwindow`. WM_CREATE call a virtual function. So a virtual function is called from the constructor. That is not allowed, so i move the `CreateWindow` into separate `create` function.

Comment: @RbMm: A c'tor should generally **fully** initialize a class instance, and allocate all resources owned by it, i.e. calling `CreateWindow` is the right thing to do. Providing a separate initialization method precludes the class from participating in RAII, which is the predominating idiom used in C++.

Comment: @IInspectable - A c'tor should generally fully initialize a class instance to default/initial values (say 0, invalid_handle_value, etc) and do task that can not fail. the Create/Init must be separate method, where we create window, open files, allocate memory etc

Comment: @RbMm: That is very much, how C++ was used 2 decades ago. Essentially "C with classes". This is nothing like C++ as of today. C'tors are allowed to fail, and lots of classes in the C++ Standard Library can. They naturally need to throw exceptions in case they do. And that is a lot better than spilling `if`-statements, to verify class invariants. The class invariant here should be, that the `hwnd` **always** stores a valid window handle. No `if`s required in the class implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by a combination of two factors:

- The order of construction of derived types.
- The fact, that [CreateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679.aspx) sends a number of messages to the window procedure before returning. From the documentation:

  > Before returning, CreateWindow sends a [WM_CREATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619.aspx) message to the window procedure. For overlapped, pop-up, and child windows, CreateWindow sends WM_CREATE, [WM_GETMINMAXINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626.aspx), and [WM_NCCREATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632635.aspx) messages to the window.

Since the `CreateWindow` is executed in the base class (`widget`) constructor, the derived class' (`olwindow`) instance has not yet been constructed, when the `WM_NCCREATE` message handler runs. Casting the pointer passed through the `CREATESTRUCT` to the derived class' type is thus an error.

To work around the issue, you need to cast the pointer back to its original type, i.e. `widget*`. If you need access to the derived object in the window procedure, you need to move window creation to a point, where it has been fully constructed.

As an alternative, you could keep calling `CreateWindow` from the base class constructor, but only cast to the derived object once it has been fully constructed, e.g. by storing a boolean value in the base class from the derived class' constructor.